# Python and Beautifulsoup extract multiple li items and its anchor text with the link

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, beautifulsoup, webrequest

I am trying to work on extracting few data from a page (https://bscscan.com/tx/0x1b6f00c8cd99e0daac5718c743ef9a51af40f95feae23bf29960ae1f66a1cff7). I am successful in grabbing some of the data that I wanted but still, I am having trouble extracting some. Any ideas will be very helpful.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib import request
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

req = Request('https://bscscan.com/tx/0x1b6f00c8cd99e0daac5718c743ef9a51af40f95feae23bf29960ae1f66a1cff7', headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
webpage = urlopen(req).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage, 'html.parser')

val = soup.find('span', class_='u-label u-label--value u-label--secondary text-dark rounded   mr-1').text
transfee = soup.find('span', id='ContentPlaceHolder1_spanTxFee').text
fromaddr = soup.find('span', id='spanFromAdd').text
token = soup.find('span', class_='hash-tag text-truncate hash-tag-custom-from tooltip-address').text

print ("From: \t\t ", fromaddr)
print ("Value: \t\t ", val)
print ("Transaction Fee: ", transfee)
print ("Tokens: \t ", token)
```

Current Output:

```
From:             0x6bdfe0696aa4f81245325c7931c117f15459e07a
Value:            0.679753633258727619 BNB
Transaction Fee:  0.00059691 BNB ($0.18)
Tokens:           PancakeSwap: Router v2
```

Wanted Output:

```
From:             0x6bdfe0696aa4f81245325c7931c117f15459e07a
Value:            0.679753633258727619 BNB
Transaction Fee:  0.00059691 BNB ($0.18)
#-- the part I cant get to work
Tokens:       Wrapped BNB (WBNB) -> https://bscscan.com/token/0xbb4cdb9cbd36b01bd1cbaebf2de08d9173bc095c 
              FaraCrystal (FARA) -> https://bscscan.com/token/0xf4ed363144981d3a65f42e7d0dc54ff9eef559a1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used css selector method which first find `div` tag and from it `ul` tag and it returns list of tags where we have to select index 1 which content the data

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib import request
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

req = Request('https://bscscan.com/tx/0x1b6f00c8cd99e0daac5718c743ef9a51af40f95feae23bf29960ae1f66a1cff7', headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
webpage = urlopen(req).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage, 'html.parser')

main_data=soup.select("div.row > div.col-md-9 >ul.list-unstyled.mb-0")[1]
for i in main_data:
    print(i.find_all("a")[-1].get_text())
    print("https://bscscan.com/token/"+i.find_all("a")[-1]['href'])
```

Output:

```
Wrapped BNB (WBNB)
https://bscscan.com/token//token/0xbb4cdb9cbd36b01bd1cbaebf2de08d9173bc095c
FaraCrystal (FARA) 
https://bscscan.com/token//token/0xf4ed363144981d3a65f42e7d0dc54ff9eef559a1
```

Or by using `find_all` method

```
main_data=soup.find_all("ul", class_="list-unstyled mb-0")
```

Comment: Thank you. I am using the find_all method as I am getting an IndexError: list index out of range sometimes.

Comment: is it also possible to extract the values inside the <span data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Current Price : $2.12 / FARA">95.834051318695064337 ($202.72)</span>. These values are before token name. I am trying but Im getting None as result.

Comment: Have you tried with `select` method and kindly creat new post so other user can also gives you suggestions

Comment: I have tried the select method. Also, I created a new post for that. Thank you.